# Issues installing netflix-desktop

Tags: 12.04, wine, netflix

I installed the Netflix desktop client and clicked on the icon, but I lost my internet connection during the Wine installations.

I tried to purge it and reinstall, but now when I click on the icon, nothing happens. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I've had it on this computer already, but had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you ever update your system by any chance? I also gather you didn't yet get it to work, ever. Try my commands below and let me know

Comment: I upgraded to 12.10 (13.04 ran slow on my netbook) and I can now get Netflix to open but I get no video or audio when I choose something. I've tried the rm -Rf command to remove and reinstall the wine browser and Netflix itself. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and re-installed it by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```